# Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am working on AI project, but I am still not very experienced in python.

I am trying to [build and test this project](https://github.com/MtDersvan/tf_playground/blob/master/wide_and_deep_tutorial/wide_and_deep_basic_serving.md).

I followed all instructions, but I still get this error when i try to launch the python script :

> TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool! Invalid
>   proto descriptor for file
>   "tensorflow_serving/apis/classification.proto":
>   tensorflow_serving/apis/classification.proto: Import
>   "tensorflow_serving/apis/model.proto" has not been loaded.
>   tensorflow.serving.ClassificationRequest.model_spec:
>   "tensorflow.serving.ModelSpec" seems to be defined in "model.proto",
>   which is not imported by
>   "tensorflow_serving/apis/classification.proto". To use it here, please
>   add the necessary import.

Would any one have an idea about what I missed ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a simular issue, this seems to be caused by upgrading tensorflow and non compatible old dependencies.

You can try to create a clean enviroment (depending on your system). For me it was a uncompatible version of tensorboard (that was installed with Anaconda and not pip). A uninstall / or reinstall fixed the issue.